# How to send data from controller to viewmodel textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on a MVC-project for fun that takes data from a public API, shows it, and calculates it depending on user input; I'm nearing the end of my goal, but one issue I've been having trouble with for the past day is blocking my progress.

The issue is as follows:

I want to be able to take data from my Controller, and show on button-press in my view, inside a writable text-box (so the user can both auto-generate data by inputting username and fetching their data from the public API, or specify their own custom data).

**View**

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Herblore";

Enter you name @Html.TextBox("Name")
<input type="submit" id="SubmitName" value="Submit" />

<script type = "text/javascript">
  $('#SubmitName').click(function() {
    var url = "/Calculator/PlayerLevelMsg";
    var name = $('#Name').val();
    $.get(url, {
      Brugername: name
    }, function(data) {
      $("#lData").html(data);
    });
  })

</script>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <h3 style="font-size: 24px">Current Level</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-md-pull-1">
                <h3><output id="lData"/></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-md-pull-1">
                <h3 style="font-size: 24px">Current EXP</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-md-pull-2">
                <h3><input type="text" id="lData" /></h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My Javascript allows me to run this controller in my calculator controller class:

```
public string PlayerLevelMsg(string BrugerName) {
    int Firemaking = 12;
    var playerdata = new OS_Efficiency_Calculator.Controllers.PlayerSearchController();
    string PlayerLevel = playerdata.GetLevel(BrugerName, Firemaking);
    string moreLevel = "PlayerLevel = 85";

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(BrugerName))
        return "Player Level" + " " + moreLevel;
    else
        return "Please enter your name.";
}
```

Which returns a string that holds a single value from the API - this shouldn't be important, in the name of reproducing my issue, commenting out the strings gathered from other classes in my project and using a basic text string will give you the same result as I'm getting, so if you wish to reproduce:

```
public string PlayerLevelMsg(string BrugerName) {
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(BrugerName))
        return "Player Level = 99";
    else
        return "Please enter your name.";
}
```

My issue is as follows; 
Using the above code, I can view the output of my `controller` just fine in the line "`<output id="lData"/>`" - however, this isn't a text-box, so the user can't edit it.

on the other hand, will not. This is likely because it's an input type, but I can't find a textbox-output type, nor am I experienced enough in MVC to fully understand why I can't just bind the textbox to the value through the ID, when that would work just fine in a general WPF application (where I've spent the most time practicing).

It seems to me that there should be some super-simple answer to this, and I hope you guys can help me, and that the semi-code provided is adequate; As said, the ideal solution is that in this picture:

[image: h]

Both of the values would be "85", but the text-box is adamant that it isn't supposed to change - Thanks so much for taking the time to look through!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Herblore";


Enter you name @Html.TextBox("Name")
<input type="submit" id="SubmitName" value="Submit" />

< script type = "text/jscript" >
  $('#SubmitName').click(function() {
    var url = "/Calculator/PlayerLevelMsg";
    var name = $('#Name').val();
    $.get(url, {
      Brugername: name
    }, function(data) {
      $("#lData").val(data);
    });
  })

< /script>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <h3 style="font-size: 24px">Current Level</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-md-pull-1">
                <h3><input type="text" id="lData"/></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-md-pull-1">
                <h3 style="font-size: 24px">Current EXP</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-md-pull-2">
                <h3><input type="text" id="lData" /></h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You need to make lData an input field with the type text and in the JavaScript function set the value of the field to the data returned from the controller.

Please visit this site to learn more about the input field: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp

Comment: That did the exact thing I was hoping for! and as expected, it was one minor change that I've completely overlooked! Thanks a lot for the help Gabriel, it's very much appreciated - I'll also look into the source you sent me, seems it'll come in handy for this project. 
I've never used Stackoverflow to post before; How do I choose an answer as correct? Or do you guys do that?

Comment: Glad I could help :) To left of my post there is an up arrow, down arrow, and a tick. Please click on the up arrow and the tick. It will upvote my answer and mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: Done! Uparrow kept telling me I needed more reputation, but hopefully it works.

Comment: No worries the mark as answer worked thanks! I didn't realize that you were a new user, you need a certain amount of reputation before you can upvote anything.